# Is there any limit on pull number in Docker Hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I want to use Docker in a production context. I want to let my collaborators pulling the latest image that I built, directly from Docker Hub. and I wonder if there is any restriction on pull number and image size in Docker Hub.
I look at Docker Hub website but I didn't find an answer to my question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't any hard limit on number of pulls or image size. However, if you have very large image (several Gigs), it might tremendously slow down your push/pull.
And if you are using Automated builds on Docker Hub, the current limits are:
* `2 hours` maximum build time
* `2 GB` RAM
* `1` CPU
* `30 GB` Disk Space

For larger Automated builds you could either break them into several Automated Builds connected by FROM statements and Repository Links, or build them locally on your machine and push them.

Comment: Where those limits are set? I think Docker has already changed them, my builds errored because a build timeout.

Comment: @CuSS: These limits are still there for Automated Builds in Docker Hub. If your builds take more than 2 hours, it will automatically time out.

Answer (score 11):

Effective from 1st November 2020, the following [restrictions](https://www.docker.com/blog/scaling-docker-to-serve-millions-more-developers-network-egress/) apply to Docker Hub:

### Pull restrictions

- Free plan – anonymous users: 100 pulls per 6 hours
- Free plan – authenticated users: 200 pulls per 6 hours
- Pro plan – unlimited
- Team plan – unlimited

The pull limit is per requesting user - not per image. Anonymous users are identified by their IP address.

A pull is defined as a request to GET the manifest of an image. This means even if you already have all the latest layers locally, running `docker pull` will still count towards the quota, even though nothing new needs downloading.

### Image retention restrictions

Images not pulled or pushed in the past 6 months are [classified as inactive](https://www.docker.com/blog/scaling-dockers-business-to-serve-millions-more-developers-storage/).

- Free accounts may retain inactive images for up to 6 months
- Pro and Team subscriptions may retain inactive images indefinitely